# Detect Country And Redirect

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsonp

Here is my code, but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
switch(country_code()){
case "IN" :
        document.location.href = "http://xxxxxxxx.biz/theme.php";
        break;
}
</script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</html>
```

I want to detect the user's country and redirect them appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wipmania link wrong it needs to have the name of a function in it that can be executed. You can use it in two ways one through an jsonp ajax call with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?",
   dataType:"jsonp"
}).done(function(data){
     switch(data.address.country_code){
        case "IN" :
           document.location.href = "http://xxxxxxxx.biz/theme.php";
        break;
     }      
});
```

or create a function in your code and then use the name of that function in the wipmania link

```
<script>
function determineCountry(data){
   switch(data.address.country_code){
      case "IN" :
         document.location.href = "http://xxxxxxxx.biz/theme.php";
      break;
   }    
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=determineCountry"></script>
```

Comment: be more descriptive than "not working" that could mean many things, are you getting an error? http://jsfiddle.net/LYJtP/ this fiddle shows it working

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with `php`. This should get you there.

```
<?php
// ccr.php - country code redirect
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
$country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
switch($country_code) {
case 'US':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/usa.php');
exit;
case 'CA':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/canada.php');
exit;
case 'GB':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/greatbritain.php');
exit;
case 'IE':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/ireland.php');
exit;
case 'AU':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/australia.php');
exit;
case 'NZ':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/newzealand.php');
exit;
default: // exceptions
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/links/allelse.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

More info and supporting plugin download:

http://www.trafficplusconversion.com/251/redirect-based-on-country/

Here is a `JavaScript` option.

http://www.geobytes.com/GeoDirection.htm

Comment: I want to use it in html. my host does not support php files.

Comment: He is already using a javascript library, its the wipmania link he is just using it incorrectly.